# Don't know why I'm getting a '/App_Code/' is not allowed because the application is precompiled?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, webdeploy

I know that there are going to be people saying, "Duplicate post!", but give me a couple minutes, please. I'm responsible for an old ASP.NET WebForms app written by God only knows who, many years ago. Whoever he/she/they were, they've long since moved on to bigger and better things. They choose to use VB.NET, so for now that's what I'm stuck with. I had to make some changes to it and decided to use what C# calls static classes, VB.NET calls these Modules. When I introduced these Visual Studio 2015 insisted upon putting the Modules into an App_Code folder, which hadn't existed previously. Now, when I try to deploy the app to the test web server, using Web Deploy, it complains with the error:

```
The directory '/Test/App_Code/' is not allowed because the application is precompiled.
```

I've searched for this message and found numerous posts, especially here on SO, saying that I should delete the App_Code folder. Ah, how do I do that when VS 2015 wants it back? Moreover, **I know for a fact** that the project is **not** precompiled when I publish it. I've checked the Publish configuration, on the Settings tab, under "File Publish Options" there's a checkbox with a label that says, "Precompile during publishing". It is and has always been CLEARED. So, what is it about this project that is making VS 2015 think its precompiling, but when I look at the configuration it says it is not precompiled? This is an old project, perhaps started using either VS 2002 or VS 2003.

[image: Settings tab in this WebForms project]

Comment: Usually, Visual Studio requires and creates the App_Code folder for Web Site projects only. If your project is a Web Application, App_Code is not required. So, keep this folder empty.

Comment: I've no idea at all whether this project I maintain was created as a Web Site or a Web Application. I strongly suspect that it was created as a Web Site.